# htaccess http to https redirection apped twice www in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Guys i have litle problem with migrating site from HTTP to HTTPS.

I want to force all to www https

1. `http://example.com` -> `https://www.example.com` (wrok)
2. `http://www.example.com` -> `https.www.example.com` (not work)

Above example return url with two www.www

https.www.www.example.com

**My code**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect to combine `http -> https` and `www` redirects into one rule:

```bash
# add www and turn on https in a single redirect rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

Your rule on the other hand is attempting to maintain same scheme (http or https) after redirect. Your rule is also working for the case when `www` is missing. You need to use `OR` between 2 conditions as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: SIte is ranked on google i need 301. I will test and i inform you. Thanks

Comment: again i have double www.www when i type in search http://www.site  i get https://www.www.site

Comment: You need to comment out your redirect rules and make sure to test it from command line curl or in new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Yes cache problem